# Why don't the latest versions of MathJax render LaTeX equations in blogdown?

Tags: r, mathjax, blogdown

**Why don't the latest versions of MathJax render LaTeX equations in blogdown?** assuming you use my methods described below:

---

I've recently updated all my R packages with:

`update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE), tinytex::tlmgr_update()`

In my blogdown YAML I set math to TRUE:

`math: true`

On my blogdown site I created the `math.html` file:

```
/your-blogdown-site/themes/hugo-theme-codex/layouts/partials/math.html
```

And I added all this to the body of my `math.html` file:

```
<script src="//yihui.org/js/math-code.js"></script>
<script async
src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
```

I got this from the [blogdown book templates section](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/templates.html) that lists MathJax `2.7.5`, although there are newer [MathJax releases](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/releases) out (eg `2.7.8`, `3.0.5`, etc). I tried these newer versions of MathJax on the code block above and it broke all the LaTeX equations on my Blogdown site. Is this because newer versions of MathJax aren't on `cdnjs.cloudflare.com` or maybe something else is going on?

Comment: Would you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @Yihui Xie Here's the steps for a repro _(1)_ Create a new blogdown site utilizing the `jakewies/hugo-theme-codex` theme. _(2)_ In the YAML of `.../content/blog/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown.Rmd` add `math: true`. _(3)_ in the body of `2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown.Rmd` add `$$1 + 1 = 2$$`. _(4)_ Create `math.html` file as explained in original question. _(5)_ Render site and see everything works as expected. _(6)_ Change MathJax version in `math.html` to `2.7.8` or `3.0.5` and re-render, you'll notice the LaTeX equations no longer work. _(7)_ I hope that helps.

Comment: Would you kindly provide the actual example (e.g. as a Github repo) instead of instructions to create a reproducible example? I appreciate the instructions, but [having something that we can immediately run would be tremendously helpful](https://yihui.org/en/2018/06/copy-and-run/).